# Distribution of XY with X and Y Bernoulli distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have a Problem with this exercise:
$X,Y:\Omega \to \{0,1\}$ are random variables with $X$~Bernoulli($\frac{1}{2}$) and $Y$~Bernoulli($\frac{3}{4}$). We also know that $P(X=Y=0)=\frac{1}{4}$

I already showed that $X$ and $Y$ are not independet. Now I want to determine the distribtion of $XY$
Therefore I have to calculate $\rho(1)=P(X=1 \cup Y=1)-P(X=1 \cap Y=1)=P(X=1)+P(Y=1)-P(X=Y=1)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$
Because $P(X=Y=1)=1-P(X=Y=0)=\frac{3}{4}$ is this true?

Therefore I thought $\rho(0)$ musst be $\frac{1}{2}$ because $\rho(0)+\rho(1)=1$
But If I try to calculate  $\rho(1)=P(X=1 \cup Y=0)+P(X=0 \cup Y=1)+P(X=0 \cup Y=0)=P(X=1)+P(Y=0)+P(X=0)+P(Y=1)+P(X=0)+P(Y=0)-P(X=Y=0)$
But thats definitly not right.
I hope you can help me

Comment: This is not about *distribution-theory* but about *probability-distributions*. Tag changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(XY=0)=P((X=0)\cup (Y=0))$$ $$=P(X=0)+P(Y=0) -P(X=Y=0)=\frac  1 2 +\frac 1  4 -\frac  1  4=\frac 1  2.$$

And $P(XY=1)=1-P(XY=0)=1-\frac 1 2 =\frac  1 2$.